# Avoid repeating code for archiving files in a directory terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I lambda functions defined in the files below:

```
../lambda_functions
├── index_to_s3.py
├── from_s3.py
├── to_s3.py
├── to_fetch.py
├── sql_fetch.py
└── sql_def.py
```

I want to archive each one of these functions into their own zip file and upload each as a separate lambda. Currently, I have to repeat this code

```
data "archive_file" "from_s3" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = local.from_s3_source
  output_path = local.from_s3_output
}
```

for each lambda to be able to do this. Is there an optimal way to keep the code dry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) and [fileset](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/fileset) for this:

```
data "archive_file" "from_s3" {

  for_each = fileset("${path.module}", "lambda_functions/*.py")
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/${each.value}"
  output_path = "${path.module}/archived_files/${trimsuffix(trimprefix(each.value, "lambda_functions/"),".py")}.zip"

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paolo. One small hurdle though. I want the destination of all zipped files to be in a directory called `archived_files` and this directory is at the same level as the folder where I ran the terraform commands. So I specified the output path to be `output_path = "${path.module}/archived_files/${each.value}.zip"` but the zipped files still go into the `lambda_functions` directory.

Comment: @theSekyi Check the updated answer. I've used trimsuffix and trimprefix to make sure the output path matches the desired filename